# How to upload a data frame on AWS as CSV directly in python?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, csv, boto3

i tried boto3 but no luck

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError

ACCESS_KEY = 'access_key'
SECRET_KEY = 'secret_key'


def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

    try:
        s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
        print("Upload Successful")
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return False
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credentials not available")
        return False


uploaded = upload_to_aws('local_file', 'information-arch', 's3_file_name')

print("Done! with the uploud")
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Hussein,

According to the [boto3Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file), you should upload your upload like this:

```
upload_file(Filename, Bucket, Key, ExtraArgs=None, Callback=None, Config=None)
```

Example:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')
```

**Parameters**

Filename (str) -- The path to the file to upload.

Bucket (str) -- The name of the bucket to upload to.

Key (str) -- The name of the key to upload to.

So on your `upload_to_aws` function called to pass the parameter like this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your dataframe directly to s3 like this:

Let's say you have a dataframe called `df`. You can use the `to_csv` option specifying your `s3` path.

It will directly save the `csv` file on S3.

**This works with pandas `versions >= 0.24`**

```
df.to_csv(s3_path, index=False)
```

From [`pandas docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-s3):

> pandas now uses s3fs for handling S3 connections. This shouldn’t break any code. However, since s3fs is not a required dependency, you will need to install it separately, like boto in prior versions of pandas.